# Passing a variable in place of a date into an excel formula by vba code

Tags: excel, vba

The commented line will work fine when made active. Efforts to replace today() with a variable is throwing error or giving 0 as the output.

```
Sub RepDate()  
Dim ReportDate As Date  
ReportDate = Application.InputBox(MsgGP, TitleMsg, FormatDateTime(Date, vbShortDate), Type:=1)  
'below line, when active is working fine; the second line which is an attempted improvement on the first, is throwing error  
'Range("AM3").Formula = "=COUNTIFS(R:R,"">=""&TODAY(),R:R,""<""&TODAY()+1,C:C,""Incident"",L:L,"">=""&TODAY(),L:L,""<""&TODAY()+1,O:O,{""Closed"",""Resolved""})"  
Range("AM3").Formula = "=COUNTIFS(R:R,"">=""&format(date(ReportDate,""dd/mm/yyyy"")),R:R,""<""&TODAY()+1,C:C,""Incident"",L:L,"">=""&TODAY(),L:L,""<""&TODAY()+1,O:O,{""Closed"",""Resolved""})"   
End Sub
```

Comment: To simplify the query, today() in below line needs to be modified         Range("AM3").Formula = "=COUNTIFS(R:R,"">="" &TODAY())"       with a variable that should pass a date to the formula in excel ...

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a variable as a variable inside of a literal string. Format `ReportDate` outside of the quote marks and splice it in with the `&` operator. Try:

```
Range("AM3").Formula = "=COUNTIFS(R:R,"">=""&" & Format(ReportDate, "dd/mm/yyyy") & ",R:R,""<""&TODAY()+1,C:C,""Incident"",L:L,"">=""&TODAY(),L:L,""<""&TODAY()+1,O:O,{""Closed"",""Resolved""})"
```

For the sake of readability, you could do something like:

```
Dim dateString As String
dateString = Format(ReportDate, "dd/mm/yyyy")
Range("AM3").Formula = "=COUNTIFS(R:R,"">=""&" & _
                        dateString & _
                        ",R:R,""<""&TODAY()+1,C:C,""Incident"",L:L,"">=""&TODAY(),L:L,""<""&TODAY()+1,O:O,{""Closed"",""Resolved""})"
```

By having the formatting as its own line you can debug it separately if needed, and splitting the formula onto three lines like that makes it clear what parts of the formula are string literals and what parts are variable.

Comment: Tried as below and not working ....       Range("am4").Formula = "=COUNTIFS(R:R,"">="" &TODAY())"
Range("am5").Formula = "=COUNTIFS(R:R,"" >= &"" & datestring )"

Comment: You are using `datestring` inside a string literal. You would need `Range("am4").Formula = "=COUNTIFS(R:R,"">="" &TODAY())" Range("am5").Formula = "=COUNTIFS(R:R,"" >= "" &" & dateString & ")" ` A variable can't be inside of quote marks and still function as a variable. It *is* somewhat confusing since you are trying to construct a string which also contains the literal symbol `&`.

Comment: Understood; however, the syntax is just not getting right...Appreciate if you can test this with     Range("am4").Formula = "=COUNTIFS(R:R,"">="" &TODAY())"